# VBA Macro Loop Through Columns in Rows and Compare Values

Tags: excel, vba

Thank you in advance for taking your time to read through this and helping me. Part of the macro that I am working on should go through rows and compare values in the last two cells of the row (columns will be different for each row thus I can't just take the values in specific two columns to compare).

Later the macro will change values in other cells depending on the finding.

What I am having difficulties with is assigning the value of the last cell in the row and cell before last.

My code is:

```
Sub compareValues()

Dim allInLastRow As Long
Dim allInLastCol As Long

Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer

Dim allInWs As Worksheet

Set allInWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All In")
allInLastRow = allInWs.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To allInLastRow 'scans through all the rows
    allInLastCol = allInWs.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    For x = 1 To allInLastCol 'scans through all the columns in each row
    
    'in here I need to have the condition that compares lastcell value to 2nd last cell value and this is the one I have a problem with
    
    Next x
Next i


End Sub
```

Any nudge toward the right direction will be much appreciated. I would love to have an answer from google, but I can't really formulate the question in a way that it would make sense to the search engine :-)

Thank you once again for your help!

Comment: Would it be safe to say, each columns last row is different ? So you are looping through each column finding the last cell in that column and comparing it with the cell above?

Comment: It's about 300 rows and for some of the columns you would have gaps row wise so wont work that way unfortunately. 

Example would be: 

Row 1 has 10 different values in 10 columns, 
Row 2 has 20 values in 20 columns,
Row 3 15 values in 15 columns
Row 4 30 Values in 30 Columns

etc. 

So if I scan column 16, then it would stop straight away as values for row 1 is empty. 

At the same time amount of rows is changing so while right now it's 300, next day it can be 400 or more.

Comment: Ah, yes I had read that originally, then somehow my mind went to last row instead of last column.. So for example: in row 1 the last column is "M" but possibly the 2nd last column is "H"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of think of finding last column in row, then finding 2nd last column in row.

```
Sub LstRw_Stuff()
    
    Dim Rws As Long, r As Range, fRng As Range, col1 As Long, col2 As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    
    Set r = Range("A1")
    Rws = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=r, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For x = 2 To Rws
        col1 = Cells(x, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rng1 = Cells(x, col1)
        s = rng1.Value
        rng1.ClearContents
        col2 = Cells(x, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rng2 = Cells(x, col2)
        rng1 = s
        
        'do whatever need to be done for comparing
        If rng1 > rng2 Then
            MsgBox "yep" & rng1.Value & ">" & rng2.Value
        Else
            MsgBox "Nope" & rng1.Value & "<" & rng2.Value
            
        End If
        
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! My main issue was assigning the value to the variable and finding the value of the 2nd last column, just wouldn't want to work for me. 

Thanks a mil!